# Delete all rows below specific row in R matching another value on a different data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, delete-row

I want to delete all rows in df1 below a specific row. This specific row always matches the first value ("Name") with df2.

df1:
| Name    | Shape| Date |
|:--------|------|------|
| 00000   | row  |10-2020|
| 00001   | row  |11-2020|
|00002    |row   |12-2020|
|00003    |row   |13-2020|
|00004    |row   |14-2020|

df2:
| Name     | Shape| Date |
|:-------- | -----|------|
|00002     |row   |12-2020|
|00003     |row   |13-2020|
|00004     |row   |14-2020|

[image]

In this case all rows on df1 below 0002 would be deleted. On df2 rows below 00002 don't necessarily match rows below 00002 on df1. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your data in a reproducible example?

Comment: @ArslanSh. i've been trying to fix this but i don't know why is not making the table as it should be.

Comment: @ArslanSh.I attached a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get `df1` with rows below the first entry of `df2$Name` removed via the `which` function (I just entered "datechar" rather than each date you have in your example since the date is not used).

```
df1 <- data.frame("Name"=seq(0,4),
                  "Shape"=rep("row",5),
                  "Date"=rep("datechar",5))
                  
df2 <- data.frame("Name"=seq(2,4),
                  "Shape"=rep("row",3),
                  "Date"=rep("datechar",3))

which(df1$Name == df2$Name[1])

df1[1:(which(df1$Name == df2$Name[1])),]
```

Comment: How would it be the case were rows are not fixed? Not 5 but each time I run it it will change.

Comment: Which rows do you mean? As long as you are always using the first row of `df2` as your criteria and taking rows from `df1` starting at row 1, the size of `df1` shouldn't matter.